# center align radio option for iOS in ionic 3 app

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

I have following code in Ionic 3. I have yes/no type radio button which are horizontally aligned. In android they are coming in center but in iOS thery are coming as right aligned. I want to make them center aligned for iOS as well. Following is the code:

```
<ion-card center>
    <ion-card-header >
        <ion-label >Q1. Are you a programming geek?</ion-label> 
    </ion-card-header>

    <ion-row radio-group>
        <ion-col width-30>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Yes</ion-label>
            <ion-radio value="1"></ion-radio>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col width-30>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label>No</ion-label>
            <ion-radio value="0"></ion-radio>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-card>
```

Following is the CSS which I have modified:

```
   .input-wrapper{
     flex: initial;
    }

    .card-md .item-md.item-block .item-inner {
        border: 0;
        justify-content: center;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done it by adding following code in css:

```
.card-ios .item-ios.item-block .item-inner {
    border: 0;
    justify-content: center;
}
```